# Changing repository in openwrt

Tags: openwrt, opkg

I have a router flashed to run openwrt (BARRIER BREAKER (Bleeding Edge, r36234))

But opkg can't find packages.

According to the error messages and /etc/opkg.conf it seems to be trying to find them at : http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/packages which is clearly a deprecated address.

So where is the new repository? And can I point opkg at it simply by updating the address in the first line of /etc/opkg.conf?

(currently :

```
src/gz barrier_breaker http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/packages
```

)

Answer (score 1):

What kind of device are you using? For `generic` `ar71xx` devices try to use the following sources (from the [OpenWrt OPKG Techref page](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/opkg#adjust_repositories)):

```
src/gz base https://downloads.openwrt.org/barrier_breaker/14.07/ar71xx/generic/packages/base
src/gz luci https://downloads.openwrt.org/barrier_breaker/14.07/ar71xx/generic/packages/luci
src/gz management https://downloads.openwrt.org/barrier_breaker/14.07/ar71xx/generic/packages/management
src/gz oldpackages https://downloads.openwrt.org/barrier_breaker/14.07/ar71xx/generic/packages/oldpackages
src/gz packages https://downloads.openwrt.org/barrier_breaker/14.07/ar71xx/generic/packages/packages
src/gz routing https://downloads.openwrt.org/barrier_breaker/14.07/ar71xx/generic/packages/routing
src/gz telephony https://downloads.openwrt.org/barrier_breaker/14.07/ar71xx/generic/packages/telephony
```